# matplotlib: Handling speech marks/quotation marks within ax.set_xlabel/ax.set_ylabel

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a niche question here, I'm unable to find any guidelines specific to this. I was wondering if anyone knew how to correctly handle the following text for an axis label within the matplotlib package:

```
ax.set_xlabel(r'$1.005116" per pixel$')
```

The quotation marks are telling the class to simply type: 1.005116, stopping at the " (which correspond to the unit of arc second).

Does anyone know the correct method to handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking advantage of the fact that you're using LaTeX:

```
ax.set_xlabel(r"$1.005116^{\prime\prime}$ per pixel")
```

(I think it looks better if the "per pixel" part is *not* in LaTeX math mode, but that's a stylistic issue.)

Comment: Worked perfectly. I will probably go with: r"$1.005116^{\prime\prime}$ $\mathrm{pix}^{-1}$"

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
ax.set_xlabel(r'''$1.005116''\ per\ pixel$''')
```

Comment: Sorry. Amended. I had very small text to test this with. According to this post; this is the correct way to do it: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/533

Comment: The edit still doesn't work...sorry. Getting closer tho. :) (P.S. The link seems more about LaTeX standards and not matplotlib translations)

Comment: Hey, see the above workaround solution. Thank you for your efforts tho Noel.

Comment: That's funny. With double `'` marks, they format as a double quote character in the output graph; as in the tex.stackexchange link. Oh well.